# Запрос на последнюю дату без повторений

Tags: sql, запрос, access, ms-access, выборка

Есть таблица Цены АЗС с полями (Код АЗС, Код топлива, Цена, Дата изменения).

Мне нужно написать запрос: пользователь вводит код АЗС, на выход - Код АЗС, Код Топлива (все 4), Цена.

В чём проблема: не получается сделать так, чтобы не выводились старые цены, т. е. нужно чтобы выводилась последняя цена данного вида топлива.

Попробовал DMax использовать, но так выводится просто самая последняя запись, невзирая на код АЗС, введённый пользователем. И тем более всего одна (а не по всем четырём видам топлива).

DISTINCT не подходит, т. к. SELECT содержит несколько полей и Дата изменения не уникальна => выведет все записи.

C Max не получилось записать запрос (чтобы получить последнюю дату и вывести только её по каждому виду топливу конкретной АЗС). - Но тут скорее я накосячил...

В конструкторе не получается составить, а с SQL едва знаком - попробовал, но не вышло.

В картинке пример данных - при вводе Кода АЗС 1, должны быть выведены 4 записи (топливо с кодом = 1 по свежей цене от 20.04.2020 41,22, старая запись не выводится).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На простом *SQL* с `Max`

```
select
  p.*
from "Цены АЗС" p,
  (select
     t."Код АЗС", t."Код топлива", max(t."Дата изменения") "Последняя дата"
   from "Цены АЗС" t
   group by t."Код АЗС", t."Код топлива") m
where p."Код АЗС" = m."Код АЗС"
and   p."Код топлива" = m."Код топлива"
and   p."Дата изменения" = m."Последняя дата"
```

может кавычки надо как-то по другому ставить. ms access видел издалека.

Comment: Спасибо, работает, но выводит код АЗС и код топлива дважды (р. и m.), а также дату изменения и "последняя дата". Как сделать, чтобы выводилось одно из полей?

Comment: Для Access квадратные скобочки вместо кавычек:

SELECT *
FROM [Цены АЗС] AS p, (select
     t.[Код АЗС], t.[Код топлива], max(t.[Дата изменения]) AS [Последняя дата]
   from [Цены АЗС] t
   group by t.[Код АЗС], t.[Код топлива])  AS m
WHERE p.[Код АЗС] = m.[Код АЗС]
and   p.[Код топлива] = m.[Код топлива]
and   p.[Дата изменения] = m.[Последняя дата];

Comment: Надо `p.*` вместо `*`, или требуемые поля перечислить

Comment: Правильно ли я изменил последнюю строку (с точки зрения "хорошего тона", так всё работает корректно), чтобы данные выводились только по одной АЗС, указанной пользователем: WHERE ( ((m.[Код АЗС]) = [Введите код АЗС]) and ((p.[Код АЗС])=[m].[Код АЗС]) AND ((p.[Код топлива])=[m].[Код топлива]) AND ((p.[Дата изменения])=[m].[Последняя дата]));

Comment: И ещё можете подсказать, как называются эти штуки p. m. - никогда не сталкивался, хочу почитать про это?

Comment: Эти сокращения называются псевдонимы таблиц (alias)

Comment: Условие правильное и "хорошее". Если критично быстродействие, то можно попробовать убрать во внутреннее условие.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь, долго мучился с этим запросом)